# Trying to make a custom scroll using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

I've been trying to make a custom scroll using jQuery and CSS and I've been partially successful. The problem is I can't figure out how to stop the scroll bar when it reaches the limit of its scroll-container. I just need to find the code section which is not letting this happen. It'd be great if someone could help with the script. I have the whole thing up and running on 
http://jsfiddle.net/ithril/va6DW/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick fix: add the folowing condition before moving the scroll:

```
if(x-35>left_limit && x-20<right_limit)
```

Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/dujaQ/

---

But i strongly suggest you to take an existing jquery plugin and adapt it to your need. Here some jquery scroll plugins with horizontal scroll support:

1. [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html)
2. [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/index.html#)

Comment: I use jScrollPane and it works like a charm, so i wouls suggest that. Fully customisable also :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Could you provide me a decent link that explains how to use jScrollPane,I tried using it but its because i dont know how to customize it and stuff. Thanks!